# Create user & drop user options not appearing in SQL Developer 4.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I downloaded and installed **Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2** and **Oracle SQL developer 4.2** on my computer (Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit) today. After installing and establishing a new connection I wanted to create a new user, so I expanded my connection (which I named "Manager") scrolled down to "Other Users" then right-clicked but the option to "Create User..." & "Drop User..." was missing.

I'm not quite sure why this has occurred (I've tried reinstalling both of them again but still the same issue), has anyone else come across such issues with SQL developer 4.2, perhaps this is a bug?

Below is an image of how it appears on my machine when I right click "other users":

[How it appears on my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkQ8G.png)

Below is an image taken from Google (as an example) of how it should look like:

[Menu appearing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnmcf.png)

Thank you

Comment: Did you give the user `Manager` the privileges needed to create and drop users?

Comment: I don't think I did, I only recall entering the connection name, username and password. @mathguy How can I give those privileges to 'Manager' connection is there an option on the toolbar or side menu?

Comment: You must be logged in as SYS to grant those privileges. Then issue `GRANT CREATE USER TO ...` and similarly for `DROP USER`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create users here:

[image]

```
View > DBA
Add a connection.
Expand tree.
Go to security.
Users.
Right-Click -> Create.
```